# Is smart escrow with ERC20 tokens fit for below scenario?

Tags: ether, bitcoin, ico

I am planning for ICO, which provides services. User need to invest some x amount of money to buy token.After buying token their will be a grace period for 10 days to generate revenue and expect returns on month basis for next 10 years. Which  model of ICO is fit for this ?

Comment: Where are these returns coming from? Is there some business happening off-chain that's making profits then buying ETH and sending them back to the token holders? Or is the money generated on-chain somehow? If so, how?

Comment: Thanks for the attention, Its like a off-chain making profits... Not based on ETH Trading ... I should send back money to the token holders on long term. > For example : User will buy coins ---> ICO company will Buy car and
> rent it->Income generated will be deposited back to the User

Answer (score 1):

Swarm City is good for off-chain 'transactional' activity which is secured by individual reputation, however, in this case you are looking for a longer term interaction between those providing investment and the activity generating a return.

It looks like you need something like a Kickstarter which is what https://www.fundyourselfnow.com/ will be trying to do.

They seem to be more geared to smaller projects vs. WINGS for example.
They do charge fees for their services, so you will need to do the math if it's right for you. This would be much simpler than creating your own token and smart contract.
Good luck!